# is there any method/api to identify master/slave node of Linux-HA cluster?

Tags: linux, crm, high-availability, pacemaker

I am setting up a Linux-HA(corosync+pacemaker) cluster which includes 2 nodes, and I defined several resources:

```
primitive virtual-ip   
primitive main-service   
primitive db  
clone db-clone
```

My question is could we identify which node will be the master node before pacemaker begin or during loading services? I mean which node will `virutal-ip` resource running on? Is there any `crm` command line api or other method?

thanks,
Emre

Answer (score 0):

As per the configuration of corosync.conf you define which ip is your primary node and which is secondary node, as per the failover approach when node1 one is down,node2 becomes primary in active/passive configuration.

crm configure show command gives you the configured information of both nodes.

crm status shows you the node which is online

Please check the link below for more information :-

http://www.tokiwinter.com/clustering-with-drbd-corosync-and-pacemaker/

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: actually I cannot find the place to define which one is the primary node in corosync.conf, could you help to figure it out?  and I want to know if any way to identify the primary/secondary role of cluster nodes BEFORE or DURING resource loading? because that will helpful to add some logic during resource loading.     and as you know, after all resources are loaded, we can use crm_mon or pcs command to get the resource location to identify the node role.